# If I have a job offer, still will I need to show proof of funds for express entry?

Tags: canada, resident-permit, skilled-migration, express-entry

I have an express entry profile. If I get a job offer, would I still need to show proof of funds for express entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you do except under certain circumstances as detailed on [this page](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1145&top=29) and listed below:

> **Do I need to include proof of funds for Express Entry?**
> You will be asked to enter in your Express Entry profile the amount of money you will have to help you settle in Canada. This is to show that you can support yourself and any family who come with you to Canada, and helps us assess which programs you may be eligible for.
>
> You will only need to meet the settlement fund requirement if it applies to the program you are invited to apply under.
>
> If you are invited to apply under the Federal Skilled Worker Program or Federal Skilled Trades Program, you will need to show that you meet the settlement funds requirement unless you:
>
> - are currently authorized to work in Canada, and
> - have a valid job offer from an employer in Canada.
>   For proof, you must get official letters from any banks or financial institutions where you are keeping money.
>
> Letter(s) must list:
>
> - all current bank and investment accounts
> - outstanding debts such as credit card debts and loans
>
> Note: You do not have to meet the funds requirement if you were invited to apply under the Canadian Experience Class.
>
> The system currently asks all applicants to provide a proof of funds document. If you don’t need to provide proof of funds, you must upload a letter explaining either that you have been invited to apply under the Canadian Experience Class, or that you have a valid job offer.

So, a summary. If you're applying under Canadian Experience class, you don't need to prove funds. If you already have a work visa for Canada AND have a job offer/are currently working, you don't need to prove funds.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying kennedy, Once I get to Canada, is there an expiration period before I can apply for PR? Let's say  I'm 6 months into the job, can I still say that I have a "job" offer?

Comment: I'm not certain about this, but I would expect so--as long as the job and employer are valid under the express entry program like job has the correct NOC code, etc.